# Running Java program with custom directory structure as Windows service

Tags: java, windows, windows-services, wrapper, yajsw

I am using YAJSW to install (and uninstall) my program as Windows service (win 32 and win 64) with the following directory structure.

How do I go about it ?

```
 apps - user works with this dir
 log - user works with this dir
 core - core of my program, user not works with this dir, here may be anything, include wrappers.
 install.cmd - user launch it to install software as windows service
 uninstall.cmd - user launch it to uninstall windows service
 settings.cmd - a very short file with user properties. javapath, ntservicename, dburl, dbuser, dbpass at all - user edit it.
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the comprehensive tutorial..

http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/

and one for windows service

https://docs.wso2.org/display/Carbon403/Installing+as+a+Windows+Service

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with the scripts located in `yajsw/bat`, specifically with `setenv.bat`.
That is the script that creates your environment variables.

Answer (score -1):

I found and look throught about 20 wrappers and helpers. Some of them is payd, some of them needs code modification, some complex, some have issues. I found only one good solution - NSSM   . I think it solve the problems as it must be solved.

Comment: NSSM is good but i must edit windows registry to edit aprameters. It's not comfortable to grand admin rights every time when changing parameters required.